# Отношения в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Получаю пост у юзера где **day = 1**, но в результате возвращает только сам пост,как мне еще сразу вывести самого юзера ? у которого этот пост ?

```
$user = User::find($id)->post()->where('day',1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос в базу

```
$user = User::with(['post' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('day', 1);
        }])->whereHas('post', function ($query) {
            $query->where('day', 1);
        })->find($id);
```

Вывод ид пользователя

```
$user->id
```

Вывод ил поста

```
$user->post->id
```

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать with https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

```
$user = User::find($id)->with(['post'=>function($query) {
      $query->where('day',1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Если использовать with , то он игнорирует  find (id)
Выводит 5 юзеров у которых day =